# Extra icon tags appearing but only 3 in the HTML

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

In the [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BaajLZm?editors=1010) codepen I have a row with 3 div tags and each div tag has 1 icon tag. However, I am getting 2 extra icon tags showing below the ID column. Where are theses extra icons coming from? When I inspect element it appears to be under my container class but it is not what is in my html. Thank you.

This is what I have in the html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4"><span ng-click="sortBy('ID')">ID <i id="id-caret" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></div>
  <div class="col-4"><span ng-click="sortBy('Name')">Bird Name <i id="bird-name-caret" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></div>
  <div class="col-4"><span ng-click="sortBy('Type')">Type of Bird <i id="bird-type-caret" class="fa fa-caret-down"</i></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs because of there is unclosed `<i>` tag:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <span ng-click="sortBy('Type')">Type of Bird 
        <i id="bird-type-caret" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```